# Special characters in DataTable column names in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

**EDIT** : I have created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcweca05/)
that shows the issue.

I define my columns the following way (pseudo-code, please don't tell me to declare the variables)

```
var cols = [];
cols.push({
    data:theNameWithSpecialCharacters,
    title:theNameWithSpecialCharacters,
    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",",".",3)
});

myDataTable = $('#theDataTable').DataTable({
    columns: cols,
    data: someDataInCorrectFormat
}).draw();
```

The datatable is correctly rendered but it doesn't show the values for the columns where there are some special characters (`[` and `]` in my case) in the column names.

Any and all help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `data` option as a string, the brackets get interpreted as array notation. The datatables [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) states the following:

> DataTables can automatically combine data from an array source, joining the data with the characters provided between the two brackets. For example: name[, ] would provide a comma-space separated list from the source array. If no characters are provided between the brackets, the original array source is returned.

So your `data: "[bla]"`  is looking for a unnamed array (which does not exist hence the empty column) to display bla's between its elements. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to escape the brackets in the string.
The easiest workaround would be to use `data` as a function and get the value from the object.

```
cols.push({
    data: function(row) {
      return row["[bla]"];
    },
    title:"[bla]",
    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",",".",3)
});
```

This is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcweca05/4/).

**Edit:**
If you don't know the columns name like the OP mentioned in the comments, the data function can be used with the index of the column.

```
cols.push({
data: function(row, type, set, meta) {
  return row[theColumns[meta.col].theColumnName];
},
title: theColumns[i].theColumnName,
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",",".",3)
});
```

Another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcweca05/15/).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. It would work if I knew beforehand what the column name is (in my fiddle it's "[bla]"). But what if that name is defined in a variable like in my pseudo-code ?

Comment: just for further clarification, I'm looping through another object and the title/data field actually looks like `theData[i].theColumnName` which is a `string`

Comment: Well when you are looping over the data anyway you could use the data as an int.
`data: i,`

Comment: I might be missing something/my comment wasn't clear/my variable name was poorly chosen.
The columns are defined from looping through an object independent of the actual underlying data. so you would have a `theColumns[i].theColumnName` and then once the datatable is defined you then get the actual data. Do I make sense ? updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dcweca05/7/

Comment: Ah sorry I've missunderstood something. You can't use `i` from the for loop because the data function is not called inside of that loop. So `row[theColumns[i].theColumnName]` would always return the value of the last column. Instead you could use the column index in the meta object. I'll update my answer according to this comment.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I had to tweak the code a little bit to make it work in my case but pointing me towards `meta` was the way to go.