# DataTables displaying blank cells but the rows have data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am having a problem with the DataTables plug-in for jQuery.
I am loading data with a JSON, but only some columns get their values displayed (see screenshot below).

[No values being displayed for the three right columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xxQx.png)

However, I printed the selected row from Datatables with `console.log(table.row(this).data())` and the print shows that there is data for the columns that appear to hold no data. Furthermore, right I am setting the `"defaultContent": ""`, but if I set it as `"defaultContent": "Not set"`, DataTables displays "Not set" for all those blank values, which is expected, but means that somehow it is not reading the content from the rows. Please check the next screenshot with the console print with data on columns "Un.", "Quant.", "Total [€]".

[Console print on the client showing that the row holds data for the columns that appear blank on the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjNYg.png)

It's worth noting that I get no errors either on the server or on the client.

Has anyone gone through this?

EDIT: Included code snippet with the initialisation settings.

```
  modelParam = configurations.especialidades[modelName].modelParam
  tableParam = configurations.datatable.specs.tableParam
  colEspecialidade = configurations.datatable.specs.colName
  especialidade = configurations.especialidades[modelName].especialidade

  // Formatting columns array for DataTables
  let cols = (() => {
    let colArr = []
    jsonSheet[0].forEach(col => {
      colArr.push({ "data": col, "title": col, "defaultContent": "" })
    })
    return colArr
  })()

  // Creating new DataTable
  table = $('#selectionTable').DataTable({
    scrollY: '70vh',
    sScrollX: '100%',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    select: true,
    cache: false,
    data: jsonSheet[1],
    columns: cols,
  })

  // Removing rows not compliant with the current model's specialization
  let indexes = table
    .rows()
    .indexes()
    .filter((value, index) => {
      return especialidade !== table.row(value).data()[colEspecialidade];
    })

  table.rows(indexes).invalidate().remove().draw()
```

`jsonSheets[0]` holds the following data:

```
[
    "Especialidade",
    "Artº",
    "Designação dos Trabalhos",
    "Item (BIM)",
    "Un.",
    "Quant.",
    "Total [€]",
    "Caract."
]
```

Comment: How did you initialize your table (initialization settings)?

Comment: Check if you are omitting the data before it goes to display. post the CODE

Comment: @cheesyMan included it in the body of the post now

Comment: @Mehrwarz Sorry, tbh I did not know exactly what code should I be including. Edited now on the body post with the initialisation of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with some characters (**dot** and **square brackets**) that are present in your field names `(Un. Quant. Total[€])` but that have a **special meaning** to DataTables when used in the `column.data` option.

- *dot* is interpreted by DT not as a literal dot, but as a *nested object syntax*
- *square brackets* are interpreted as *array notation*

In both cases, DT searches for data that are not found, so the column is empty.

You can see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/cheesyman/pen/KKZXWjx) where it works perfectly removing these special characters from the field names.

You can also take a look at the [DataTables doc page](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) referring to this question (inside the ***string*** box).

A workaround for the dot is to escape it with a double slash, the square brackets unfortunately are not escapable.

Maybe in this case the `function(row, type, set, meta )` syntax to set the data for the column could be a better choice.

See also [Special characters in DataTable column names in JQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376481/special-characters-in-datatable-column-names-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: That was the issue. Worked like a charm! thank you!